# Schedule an event for last Sunday (or another day of week) of each month

Tags: google-calendar

How do I set a reminder in Google Calendar for an event that occurs on every Sunday before the 1st of the following month?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. In the main Google Calendar view, click 'Create'
2. Click the text box representing the start date (The datepicker pops up)
3. Choose a month that has 5 Sundays (For example, August 2015)
4. Pick the 5th Sunday in that month (For example, August 30, 2015)
5. Click the 'Repeat...' checkbox (The repeat popup appears)
6. Choose the following options

   - Repeats: Monthly
   - Repeat every: 1 months
   - Repeat by: day of the week

That's it! It should now say under summary: **Monthly on the last Sunday**, which I believe is what you wanted.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, any idea how to do the same thing but for either the last Sunday or Saturday, whichever is closer to the end of the month? I'll write up a separate question if you can answer it :)

Comment: Hmm....I'm not sure about that one. I don't know of a way to say Saturday OR Sunday.

Comment: Item 3 above is useful. Took me ages to realise last Sunday only appeared when there were 5 Sundays in the chosen month.

Comment: This is not working.  I need to schedule a reminder for Memorial Day every year, which is the last Monday of May.   The reminder has to be in the past so it will show up in future years before another May occurs with 5 weeks.  I set a reminder in 2017 and set it to the last Monday.  I see the reminder shows up the last Monday of 2019, but not 2018 (who cares), 2020, 2021-2023 (which actually have 5 mondays)... I stopped at 2025. If I edit the 2019 event it says it repeats "every 12 months on the fourh Monday" which is also not true as it doesn't show up in future years there either.

Comment: I went back to look at the 2017 entry to try to edit it, and now it's gone as well...

Answer (score 1):

If you actually want a day on the 5th week of every month (versus the last week), the Google Calendar UI does not support this, but you can do it by importing an .ics file that looks something like this:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Google Inc//Google Calendar 70.9054//EN
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:PUBLISH
X-WR-CALNAME:5th Week Examples
X-WR-TIMEZONE:America/Los_Angeles
X-WR-CALDESC:Examples of events on the 5th week of every month
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:America/Los_Angeles
X-LIC-LOCATION:America/Los_Angeles
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
TZOFFSETFROM:-0800
TZOFFSETTO:-0700
TZNAME:PDT
DTSTART:19700308T020000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=3;BYDAY=2SU
END:DAYLIGHT
BEGIN:STANDARD
TZOFFSETFROM:-0700
TZOFFSETTO:-0800
TZNAME:PST
DTSTART:19701101T020000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=11;BYDAY=1SU
END:STANDARD
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART;TZID=America/Los_Angeles:20200930T190000
DTEND;TZID=America/Los_Angeles:20200930T230000
RRULE:FREQ=MONTHLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=WE;BYSETPOS=5;WKST=SU
DTSTAMP:20200828T165948Z
CREATED:20200828T165925Z
DESCRIPTION:
LAST-MODIFIED:20200828T165925Z
LOCATION:
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY:Event: 5th Wednesday of every Month
TRANSP:OPAQUE
BEGIN:VALARM
ACTION:DISPLAY
DESCRIPTION:This is an event reminder
TRIGGER:-P0DT0H10M0S
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

The most important line in there is this one:

```
RRULE:FREQ=MONTHLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=WE;BYSETPOS=5;WKST=SU
```

Once imported you can edit everything about the event, except for the repeat schedule. The UI will say "Unsupported Recurrence" since it has no way to display this pattern.

Another thing to note, is that if you export this event from your Google Calendar to give to someone else to import it will revert back to a once every week repeat pattern, due to the way they export the event.

That all being said, importing this works great and will get you what you need.