# Schedule a reminder for Memorial Day every year

Tags: google-calendar, google-calendar-reminders

Memorial Day in the United States falls on the last Monday of May.

I figured I could just set a reminder for the last day of May every 12 months, but it doesn't offer "last Monday of May" unless May has 5 Mondays.

[This answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/85060/36768) doesn't work.  I can't set a recurring reminder in the past, because it instead says "recurring reminder created today" as if I created it at the next May, which doesn't have five weeks, so it changes it to "fourth Monday in May" which is wrong, and after that, it *doesn't even show up for any subsequent fourth **or** last Monday's in May for future years!*

I also can't select a future May to start the event, because there isn't a May with 5 Mondays again until 2021, which means I would miss two years of reminders.

I thought as a workaround I would go ahead and create the reminder in 2021 to cover that and all subsequent years, and then manually create 2019 and 2020 reminders (although this is *not* an acceptable general solution, because of the arbitrary number of years ahead you have to go to get a month with 5 of whatever day of the week you are interested in), but when I did that, the reminder *still* only showed up for 2022 and no years after that!

Comment: The answer you link is working for me.  I just scheduled on May of 2017 with a 12 month recurrence and it shows a reminder for May of 2019

Comment: @KCBaltz Thanks, I have noticed that once I mark a reminder as done, the next occurrence usually shows up ... however, there is one case where this did not happen.

Comment: I wrote "reminder" when I should have written "calendar entry".  I guess i'll have to wait until next year to see if the reminder works unless I get ambitious and create a test event in June.

Comment: @KCBaltz My test cases all failed on the second year, which may be why I haven't seen any failures yet for real events.  I guess I'm just going to have to keep a close eye every time I clear a yearly reminder to make sure it shows up for the next year.